# ActiveMQ threads

Tags: multithreading, activemq-classic

How long does the threads take to stop and exit for `ActiveMQConsumer`? I get a segmentation fault on closing my application. Which I figured out was due to the ActiveMQ threads. If I comment the consumer the issue is no longer present. Currently I am using `cms::MessageConsumer` in activemq-cpp-library-3.9.4.

I see that the `activemq::core::ActiveMQConsumer` has `isClosed()` function that I can use to confirm if the consumer is closed and then move forward with deleting the objects thereby avoiding the segmentation fault. I am assuming this will solve my issue. But I wanted to know what is the correct approach with these ActiveMQ objects to avoid the issues with threads?

I was using the same session with consumer and producer, but when the broker is stopped and started the ActiveMQ reconnect was adding threads. I am not using failover.

So I have separated the session to send and receive and have instantiated connection factory, connection, and session for each separately. This design has no issues until the applications memory was not getting cleaned up due to above segmentation fault.

That's why I wanted to know when should I use `cms::MessageConsumer` vs `ActiveMQConsumer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ Website has [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/overview) with examples for the CMS client.  I'd suggest reading those and following the example code in how it shuts down the connection and the library resources prior to application shutdown to ensure that resources are cleaned up appropriately.

As with JMS the CMS consumer instance is linked with the thread in the session that created it so if you are closing down a good rule to follow is to close the session to ensure that message deliveries get stopped before you delete anything consumer instances.